# How is GKE/EKS Pod's IP address accessible from the network?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-eks

I thought by design, one should access pod via exposed services.  However, I find that on GKE and EKS, I can ping the pod address from instance outside of Kubernetes cluster.

```
>> kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP              NODE                                               NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
dnsutils                 1/1     Running   4          4h5m    10.80.12.19     ip-10-80-26-113.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal    <none>           <none>
network-test             1/1     Running   0          4h11m   10.80.11.192    ip-10-80-26-113.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal    <none>           <none>
ntest-6877545bdb-7h498   1/1     Running   0          8h      10.80.29.36     ip-10-80-60-104.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal    <none>           <none>
ntest2-854bd7cb6-tnbgt   1/1     Running   0          8h      10.80.116.168   ip-10-80-111-130.ap-northeast-2.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
```

Above is output from EKS.  I can ping 10.80.x.x (pod) IP address within same VPC/subnet.

I can't do this when I try the same on my on-prem Kubernetes cluster.

Is it suppose to do this? If yes, how can I set up the same on my on-prem cluster?

Comment: when you say you can ping the pod are you able to ping it from outside the kubernetes cluster?

Comment: yes - I created a EC2 instance on the same VPC/subnet and I can ping the pod from the EC2.

Answer (score 2):

This is being possible by the CNI plugin used. GKE uses GKE native CNI and EKS uses [EKS CNI](https://github.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s).

From EKS docs

> Amazon EKS supports native VPC networking via the Amazon VPC CNI
>   plugin for Kubernetes. Using this CNI plugin allows Kubernetes pods to
>   have the same IP address inside the pod as they do on the VPC network.

In on prem cluster you will not be able to use these CNIs.